# why does gap width not change when creating a diagram using python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I create a diagram in a PowerPoint presentation using python-pptx, I specify the gap width equal to 0%, but when creating the gap width of the diagram remains the default value (150%), what am I doing wrong?

```
import openpyxl
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Cm
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

# Задаем пути к файлам
pptx_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_pptx\3_slide_pattern.ppt"
excel_files = [
    r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_pptx\072022.xlsx",
    r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_pptx\082022.xlsx",
    r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_pptx\092022.xlsx",
]

# Читаем данные из файлов Excel
data = []
for file in excel_files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']
    product_name = ws['B5'].value
    production = ws['D5'].value / 1000
    deviation = ws['F5'].value
    data.append((product_name, production, deviation))

# Открываем существующую презентацию и выбираем первый слайд
prs = Presentation(pptx_path)
slide = prs.slides[0]
chart_data = CategoryChartData()

chart_data.categories = [item[0] for item in data]
chart_data.add_series('Выпуск продукции', [item[1] for item in data])

# Изменяем тип диаграммы на горизонтальную столбчатую диаграмму
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED, Cm(12.69), Cm(3.78), Cm(8), Cm(2), chart_data
).chart

chart.series[0].gap_width = 0

# Настраиваем диаграмму
bar_colors = [RGBColor(124, 158, 130), RGBColor(66, 116, 75), RGBColor(24, 85, 35)]

for i, point in enumerate(chart.series[0].points):
    point.format.fill.solid()
    point.format.fill.fore_color.rgb = bar_colors[i]
    point.data_label.text_frame.text = f"{data[i][1]:.0f}"
    point.data_label.text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(105, 109, 111)

# Удаляем название диаграммы, сетку и оси
chart.has_title = False
chart.value_axis.has_major_gridlines = False
chart.value_axis.visible = False
chart.category_axis.visible = False



# Сохраняем презентацию
prs.save(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_pptx\3_slide_complete.pptx")
print("готово")
```

I tried it like this:

```
chart.series[0].overlap = 100
chart.series[0].gap_width = 0
```

and:

```
chart.gap_width = 0
```

I run the code in Jupiter notebook, maybe this is the problem, checked and reinstalled all the libraries, like everything should be ok

Answer (score 1):

it was necessary to explicitly specify which chart object to apply gap_width to

```
bar_plot = chart.plots[0]
bar_plot.gap_width = 0
```